# Bitbucket API - Unable to Generate Access Token from JWT

Tags: jwt, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm using Bitbucket Connect App and getting `JWT` token from webhook event.
When I am using the latest `JWT` to get `access token`, the access token API returning blank in response.

**API:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: JWT {jwt_token}" \ https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \ -d grant_type=urn:bitbucket:oauth2:jwt
```

**Example:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: JWT ey*****XVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOi****asdfQ.**BBD**" \
  https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
  -d grant_type=urn:bitbucket:oauth2:jwt
```

**Response**

`{blank}`

**API Reference**:

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/oauth-2/

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "When I am using the latest JWT to get access token, the access token API returning blank in response?" you can't get an access token using an access token?" You need a refresh token for that

Comment: Which flow are you trying to use? as described here? https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/oauth-2/

Comment: I am using this : **4. Bitbucket Cloud JWT Grant (urn:bitbucket:oauth2:jwt)**

<https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/oauth-2/#4--bitbucket-cloud-jwt-grant--urn-bitbucket-oauth2-jwt->

Comment: Sorry don't know, deleted my answer as well as it was not correct

Comment: In the sample here https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bb-cloud-jwt-grant-sample-app/src/9b116795c70d7affb723d1c4a0cff979cb605d52/routes/index.js#lines-125  (line 125)  they also add  a content type, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this documentation to generate Access Token and it worked.
https://pawelniewiadomski.com/2016/06/06/building-bitbucket-add-on-in-rails-part-7/

Most of the Part for generating access token using **Bitbucket Cloud API**

```
def get_access_token
  unless current_jwt_auth
    raise 'Missing Authentication context'
  end

  # Expiry for the JWT token is 3 minutes from now
  issued_at = Time.now.utc.to_i
  expires_at = issued_at + 180

  jwt = JWT.encode({
                       iat: issued_at,
                       exp: expires_at,
                       iss: current_jwt_auth.addon_key,
                       sub: current_jwt_auth.client_key
                   }, current_jwt_auth.shared_secret)

  response = HTTParty.post("#{current_jwt_auth.base_url}/site/oauth2/access_token", {
      body: {grant_type: 'urn:bitbucket:oauth2:jwt'},
      headers: {
          'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Authorization' => 'JWT ' + jwt
      }
  })

  if response.code == 200
    Response.new(200, response.parsed_response)
  else
    Response.new(response.code)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I added the `sub` key to the payload. Set the value to the value received in `clientKey` during the app installation lifeycle event.